# How to add a tile layer in Mapbox's Terra example

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl

I'm looking at Mapbox's Terra example: https://www.mapbox.com/labs/terra/#15.0805/-25.3506/131.0368/-6.0332/0.0001

and wondering if it would be possible to drape another tile layer over the plane mesh?

This is easy to do with Mapbox GL JS:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/

but how would I do it in three.js?

Comment: still into this? I´m currently writing a simple js library for three.js to use any wmts/tms service. that was inspired by the terra example and will be similar to use as leaflet, needing a tiled dem and whatever (tiled) drape layer you want. as it is part of my phd and bound to it´s dreaded deadlines, it should be ready end of january. I hope. got any experience with three js?

Comment: hey @ThingumaBob, ever finish your library?

Comment: @btjakes I did, but due to really weird decisions made by my supervisors I am not allowed to open source it yet...